# Main frame Timer is not called in BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, progress-bar

I have a very basic requirement. While the background work in progress, I want to show a progress bar. I used the visible property to manage the appearance of the progress bar. Progress bar is itself a user control which is instantiated in the main frame.

In the background worker, I update the listview of main frame using Invoke API. What I was expecting was that progress bar should be working while list is being populated, but I found that timer of the progress bar user control is not being called.

Here is the code snippet:

```
// Assigning back ground work
this.backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new  System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(this.FetchDataFromDB);
this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(this.DoneWork);
```

FetchDataFromDB API is called by background worker, which in turn call the PopulateList API of the main frame.

```
    private void FetchDataFromDB(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs args)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new M_Delegate(() => this.PopulateList()));
        }
    }

    private void DoneWork(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Disable progress bar
        circularProgressBar_usercontrol1.Visible = false;
    }

    private void PopulateList()
    {
        ..... Populate listview of the main frame
    }
```

This is how I invoked the background worker.

```
// Making progress bar visible
circularProgressBar_usercontrol1.Visible = true;
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
```

circularProgressBar_usercontrol1 has the timer, which control the progress bar. I added a breakpoint at timer1_Tick API of the timer, and I found that this API is invoked only after background worker job is done.

Due to this, timer is not working during background worker and hence, my progress bar is not working correctly.

Please tell me the issue with my code.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run all the code to read from DB on the main thread because you immediately schedule work back to main thread.

The goal of using worker thread is to run slow operation on background thread and than quickly send completed result to UI thread (note that you need also avoid giving results of LINQ queries as they use lazy execution and may still run slow code on target thread - see `.ToList` call in the sample below):

```
private void FetchDataFromDB(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs args)
{
    // slow reading from DB on worker thread
    var listFromDb = this.ReadDataFromDb().ToList();

    // send populated result to main thread
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(AddItemsToUiList(listFromDb)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. I have one doubt here, when I read DB on the main thread, why the timer of the progress bar is not being called ? Is it because that it is a sequential code ?

Comment: @AbhishekMittal yes, because one thread can handle only one synchronous operation at time.